# Stick element A to top and B to bottom without position: absolute

Tags: html, css

Following layout

```
-----
  A
-----
WHITE
WHITE
WHITE
-----
  B
-----
```

In order to achieve this layout I can use

```
position: absolute;
top/bottom: 0;
```

Works fine, the problem is, Element A can grow. So with `position: static` it works how it should: Element B can grows, the div gets some scrolling if not all of it can be displayed anymore and Element A can still be seen as part of the scrolling.

When I apply my CSS rules though, Element B grows until Element A is covered by B. Z-Index won't help here, so I pretty much want the standard behavior with `position: static`.

Is there any other way? I was thinking of a middle white element which keeps shrinking as B grows.

Comment: And with position fixed ?

Comment: @Pik_at same problem

Comment: You can do that easily with __CSS Flex Layout__. Wait till I give an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluid sticky footer using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609702/fluid-sticky-footer-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/xr1as8hh/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="element">A</div>
        <div>White<br/>White<br/>White</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">B</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
    .top {
        border: 1px solid red;
        flex: 1;
        overflow: auto;
    }
        .element {
            padding-bottom: 200px;
        }

    .bottom {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```